# Update Snowflake View using MS Access DB

Tags: sql, ms-access, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to update a Snowflake view using MS Access DB?

Answer (score 0):

[Snowflake - Limits on Views](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-introduction#limitations-on-views) states

> Views are read-only (i.e. you cannot execute DML commands directly on a view).

MS Access can query a Snowflake view.